# Linking libjpeg to an xCode project for iOS dev

Tags: c++, objective-c, iphone, xcode, libjpeg

Good evening,

I have been working on a C++ project from someone of my University which I had to improve for my Bachelor thesis. It basically uses the library libjpeg to do some computation resulting in a steganographic process in order to embed a message into a given image.

Now that the C++ code works smoothly, I'd like to create a little iOS app allowing the user to encrypt whatever message he'd like into an image of his choice. So I created an xCode project following this procedure: [using c++ in an iOS app](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-in-an-ios-app-with-objective-c/)

I also found the following file: [libjpeg for iOS](https://gist.github.com/dulaccc/25dbe620422c07e0253e) which allowed me to compile libjpeg for iOS. Since I'm not so sure how to use the framework freshly created and couldn't find anything sufficiently convincing on the internet, I put all the files (.c and .h) of the libjpeg library into my "include" folder where I have my own .hpp.

xCode only throws me the following error:

[xCode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pomQJ.png)

From what I could gather on several posts, I have to modify the build options of my xCode project to link manually the library, so I tried the following:

[Other linking flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEdAJ.png)

[Library search path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyhc9.png)

This wasn't enough to do the trick and I'm still struggling with the same error xCode throws at me. Any help would be very appreciated on how to proceed!

Thanks a lot,
Theo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add the `.c` files to your project, add the `libjpeg.a` file produced by your build to your project. Add the `.h` files as you are already doing, or edit the project settings to include their containing folder in the search path.

HTH

Comment: First off, thank you for your answer. I am getting this new error now:

[error](https://imgur.com/sov7X2z)

And here's how my include folder looks like:

[include folder](https://imgur.com/Jo68Th0)

Comment: You are getting linking errors suggesting the library is not part of your project. Check it is listed in your project files in Xcode, check the Build Phases section of the settings that the library is listed under "Link Binary With Libraries", etc. If you're still stuck check the Xcode docs for linking with a library.

Comment: I finally got it working except one thing. For the people struggling with the library: just compile manually a fat library including all sub-libraries created by the script given here: [CODE](https://gist.github.com/eminarcissus/108c2ac0c7c9124b65709b44edabd424). Use the command `sudo libtool -static arm64/libjpeg.a armv7/libjpeg.a armv7s/libjpeg.a i386/libjpeg.a x86_64/libjpeg.a -o libjpeg.a`. Then follow the above steps.

That being said, here's the new error I get: my code won't accept to call one of my function and throws the following error: [ERROR](https://imgur.com/a/kQKLx).